# validate request body before uploading a file using multer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, multer

I want to upload user profiles according to their school ids

```js
// import multer
var multer = require('multer')

// import school and student models
const { School } = require('./models/school/school.model.js')
const { Student } = require('./models/student/student.model.js')

// configure multer
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const dir = `./uploads/schools/${req.body.schoolId}/students`
        fs.exists(dir, exist => {
            if (!exist) {
                return fs.mkdir(dir, { recursive: true }, error => cb(error, dir))
            }
            return cb(null, dir)
        })
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `student-${normaliseDate(new Date().toISOString())}.${file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1]}`)
    }
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('profile')

app.post('/student', function (req, res) {
    // check if submitted school id is valid
    let school = await School.findOne({ _id: req.body.schoolId })
    if (!school)
        return res.send(`School of id ${req.body.schoolId} doesn't exist`)

    // upload the profile pic
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err)
    })

    // save the student
    let newStudent = new Student({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        school: req.body.schoolId,
        profile: req.file.filename
    })

    const saveDocument = await newStudent.save()
    if (saveDocument)
        return res.send(saveDocument).status(201)
    return res.send('New College not Registered').status(500)
})
```

but when I try to access req.body before uploading the profile I get an empty object.

I would upload the profiles in a tempolary folder and move them later but what if the submitted school id is invalid ?? this will require me to delete the uploaded file. so I want to make sure the submitted details are valid and then upload the profile later save the student.

Comment: show us where you are validating school id

Answer (score 0):

Check your codes, you are using **await** but async is nowhere to be found. Though it may not be the cause of getting an empty req.body object.

```
let school = await School.findOne({ _id: req.body.schoolId })
const saveDocument = await newStudent.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how you are sending data to the backend but try these option it may work

- remember that when javascript is sending `POST` data from `client` to `server` it sends them according to how they are arranged so if you have your client form like this

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="file" name="pic">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="number" name="age">
</form>
```

it will send `file` named `pic` first, then `text` named `username` secondly and finally send `number` named age, so if you are getting empty `req.body` while the file has not been completely uploaded you might check this  if it is the problem because `javascript` process them on an order according to how they were sent

i hope this gonna help